# npm -g list not displaying anything (but npm list will)

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm having a weird issue. I can't seem to find a stackoverflow with someone with a similar issue (which is rare) so I thought I would ask.

I can't seem to get `npm -g` list to display anything. Not even `--empty`. Just a blank line.

I've tried reinstalling `npm`. I updated Node. I reinstalled package in the the global scope (which work). I can display local `npm list`. It just doesn't work with the `-g` flag.

Nothing so far as I can find is broken, and all my packages work as expected, so this is more an annoyance than a blocking issue. But I can't for the life of me figure out what is causing the behavior?

Anyone got a clue?

Screenshots of behavior below

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. In my case it was caused by broken symbolic link in my global node_modules folder, so I guess `npm list -g` get confused by that. As soon as I removed the broken symlink everything got back to normal.

Try to run `ls -l $(npm root -g)` and see if you have any errors there.